# I need no definition. Flowing like water, from port to port

Tags: riddle, word

> I need no definition.
>   Flowing like water,
>   From port to port.
>
> Hurting none,
>   I am mightier than the sword.
>   Many tremble beneath my power.
>   But I may be purged from afar.
>
> Many uses,
>   Both good and evil.
>   I am undetermined until the thinking makes me so.
>
> Spun in to anything,
>   I can motivate the masses.

---

**What am I?**

(Bonus points if you can name the reference(s))

Comment: The line "I am mightier than the sword" was a dead giveaway of the answer. In the future, I would try to obscure or exclude standard aphorisms like that one.

Comment: And keep riddling on here! The world needs more riddlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> Words

Explanation:

I need no definition

> Everyone is familiar with words, that is, they need no introduction.
>
>  Also, language users can understand words even if they are unable to formulate an explicit dictionary definition.

Flowing like water,
From port to port.

> This seems like a poet description of words coming out of people's mouths and into people's ears (*from port to port*).

Hurting none,

> This is an allusion to the old adage "Sticks and stones may break my bones, but names will never hurt me."

I am mightier than the sword.

> This is an allusion to the adage "The pen is mightier than the sword." (This clue was a big giveaway.)

Many tremble beneath my power.
But I may be purged from afar.

> I'm not sure about these lines. Maybe something about fear, stuttering, censorship, and/or electronic communication.

Many uses,
Both good and evil.

> Martin Luther King Jr. used words; so did Joseph Stalin.

I am undetermined until the thinking makes me so.

> It is in virtue of human thought that words have meaning. (At least *some* philosophers of language think so. For example, Paul Grice.)
>
>  Thought is also useful for disambiguating words, for instance, deciding if an occurrence of "bank" refers to a river or a financial institution.

Spun in to anything,

> "Spinning a yarn" is an idiom meaning to tell a story.
>
>  Given the [generativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generativity) of language, and the fact that language contains [open classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech#Open_and_closed_classes) of words,  stories can be about anything.

I can motivate the masses.

> Words can be used to persuade people. [Rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric) (on at least one meaning) is the study of this use of words.